# Get variable definition as string

Tags: php, arrays

Is there any built-in way to get an array's definition in string format? The out put should be valid PHP code for defining the same array.

For example:

```
$arrayDefinition = array_encode($anArray);
```

Should return something like:

```
['a' => 'x', 'b' => 'y']
```

Comment: var_dump is the answer

Comment: print_r() perhaps? But if you need to pass arrays from one script to another, serialize them

Comment: Also, `array_encode` would be more appropriate.

Comment: if i understand you right you want a string that can be returned into an array, so use `json_encode()`, `json_decode`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php).

Example:

```
$arr = [1,2,3];
echo $str = var_export($arr, TRUE);
```

output:

```
array ( 0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 3, )
```

Comment: Nice one Rizier, much more elegant.

Comment: faster and timing move..:D..;)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is any use to you but found from http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php#77234

```
 <?php
    echo '<pre>'; // This is for correct handling of newlines
    ob_start();
    var_dump($var);
    $a=ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    echo htmlspecialchars($a,ENT_QUOTES); // Escape every HTML special chars (especially > and < )
    echo '</pre>';
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

var_export — Outputs or returns a parsable string representation of a variable.
You also refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php

```
<?php
var_export(array (1, 2, array ("a", "b", "c")));
?>
```

This will output like following:

```
array ( 0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => array ( 0 => 'a', 1 => 'b', 2 => 'c', ), )
```